# How to toggle ui-sref active/inactive link ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Consider the following:

```
   <ul>
        <li id="dashboard" data-ui-sref-active="selected">
            <a data-ui-sref="home">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
<li id="jobs" data-ui-sref-active="selected">
        <a data-ui-sref="home.foo">Foos</a>
        <ul>
            <li data-ui-sref-active="selected">
                <a data-ui-sref="home.foo.foo1">Foo 1 list</a>
            </li>
            <li data-ui-sref-active="selected">
                <a data-ui-sref="home.foo.foo2">Foo 2 list</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Problem is if the user currently click on another link, this "Dashboard" link state is still active.

How can I toggle the state active/inactive for Dashboard when user clicks it or clicks another link

Update:

I have tried this ui-sref-active-eq and it does work, however I cannot set this state back to active

Comment: I added a plnkr in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are at child state of your `home` state, and thus it will always be active.

Use `ui-sref-active-eq` instead

According to the docs:

> Will activate when the ui-sref's target state or any child state is active. If you need to activate only when the ui-sref target state is active and not any of it's children, then you will use ui-sref-active-eq

Edit: Added in [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/T72MVfVqCAwVafihxbPj?p=preview) for reference.

Comment: i've tried this but that makes my link un-clickable, also doesnt cover my requirement where the parent needs to be active also

Comment: @Harry it should be working. Maybe you used the wrong syntax? attached a plnkr for reference.

Comment: thanks, i only implemented the -eq on the parent and not the childs. it works :)